# Implementing a mini social graph

Tags: ruby, facebook, mongodb, graph

I have an application where users of the application can have many contacts ( other users of the application ) related to them. I would like to maintain a relation between a single user and its set of contacts. At any given point of time, I do NOT need to know anything more than the direct set of contacts for a particular user, i.e, contacts of contact of a particular user is not of relevance in this application.

Any suggestion on how to organise this data within the database? Please note that the number of users could go up really high.

Just to add some extra info, the database I am using right now is Mongodb and language being used is Ruby.

The only model right now before thinking of building all these relations is the Users model which stores details of each user registered onto the application. Now as I mentioned above, I need to built the specified relation between the user and its set of contacts. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just store a list of contacts for each user? If each user is a document, you could just store an array of `_id`s.

Comment: Agreed with you, moreover the list should lives as long as the user account exists so the "embedded" way makes sense.